# Making webdriverio to run test cases for multiple similar pages?

Tags: automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am using [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/api.html) to automate certain test cases. I am using the POM style to organise my project. I am facing an issue where I want to use the same test code for n pages, and all of the pages are clones (only theme changes),is there any way I can set webdriverio to run the testcases for all of the websites and give me results individually?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the tests using TestNG, then use DataProviders aka make your tests accept parameters (like the page name you wanna test) and create a functon that wil provide these parameters. IF you annotate these functions properly, TestNG will record different resuts for each iteration. There is an extension for JUnit that provides the same for that framework as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really wonder if there is something similar to testng for webdriver io

Comment: if you use pom (I assume maven) then just annotating your test methods as @Test  and adding the required dependency to TestNG is all what you need to